# How to create distribution zip package from a java project in netbeans? containing .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file, netbeans

I experimented so heavily on netbeans, and I got a way to create .bat file to run java project on Windows OS. the .bat file is inside a zip file. The zip file is structured like this, in a netbeans java project.

[image: the zip file]

inside the zip, is structured like this:
[folder name]->[folder named "bin"]->[2 files]

the [2 files] is:

1. a file named after the project name, without file extension. in this
   case is "Replicator3". this is a "start up script for UN*X".
2. a bat file. in this case is "Replicator3.bat".

[image: the bat file contained inside "bin" folder]

beside bin folder, there are also lib folder as you can see on picture above. the lib folder contains project .jar file and 2 .jar of library files.

[image: content of lib folder]

I made this zip file and its content with netbeans, but I forgot how to remake this zip file. I reinstall Windows OS and now I cant remember how I did this.

Please help me create this zip file in netbeans. If I remember correctly, I did this on Netbeans 8.2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observation, that zip package might created using gradle

Comment: thank you.. you really save my life. may God bless you